# ListView Items covered by keyboard or jump up when new items arrive

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am building a chat app like WhatsApp with Firestore as backend.
My chat UI consists of a Scaffold, an AppBar, a ListView and an input field with a send button at the bottom.
The listview is just displaying the stream of a *messages* collection in Firestore.

Here is the code of the ListView

```
Column(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
  children: [
    Flexible(
      fit: FlexFit.loose,
      child: ListView.builder(
        controller: _scrollController,
        reverse: true,
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemCount: _messages.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return ChatMessageTile(
            message: _messages[index],
          );
        },
      ),
    ),
    InputBar(
      isActive: _activeChat.chat?.isActive,
      callback: (String msg) async {
        _activeChat.sendChatMessage(messageText: msg);
      },
    ),
  ],
),
```

**Scenario 1: reverse: true**
When I am using `reverse: true`, new messages gets pushed to the top of the listview which causes the view to jump by one message height. There is (of course) no nice animation, because the list just gets re-rendered. Furthermore if the user scrolls up to read older messages and a new message arrives, the view jumps by the height of that particular message.
The good thing about that is, when the user opens the keyboard, the listview gets pushed up by the height of the keyboard. The view/scrollposition does not change.

**Scenario 2: reverse: false**
In this scenario, the top of the list is really the top of the listview. That means new messages arrive at the bottom of the list and I have to do a "scroll to the maxExtent" action, which causes the nice side effect of having a nice animation of new messages. Plus if the user scrolled to older messages, the view does not jump when new messages arrive.
The only big negative thing about that scenario is, when the user opens the keyboard, it does not push up the list. So actually it does push up the bottom of the listview, but it does not push up the currently viewed message. The same behavior is happening when the user scrolled up to older messages. When he taps the input bar and the keyboard opens, it covers the messages which the user just looked at.

**What I want:**

- a listview of chat messages which are nicely animated when new messages arrive
- the listview should not jump on new messages
- the keyboard should not cover recent messages

I hope that describes my problem well enough for you to understand and I hope somebody can help me or at least give me a suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Try to Remove `Flexible` and wrap `Column` with `SingleChildScrollView`,

If needed add physics to NeverScroll to ListView

Hope this will work!

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn’t solve my problem